# Visual C++ for linux extension : upload other projects output

Tags: linux, visual-studio, visual-c++, mono

I am using the [Visual C++ for Linux Development](https://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/725025cf-7067-45c2-8d01-1e0fd359ae6e) extension to code a C++/C# application using [Mono](http://www.mono-project.com/docs/advanced/embedding/).

I have one solution with the C++ main project and the C# assemblies projects.

How can I do to upload the C# projects ouput to the C++ output directory, so I can debug without having to upload everything myself ?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

The Linux extension's CopySources MSBUILD task copies all of the following items that part of your project: Content, ClInclude, ClCompile and None items. You can also customize it more, and even add your own custom items to the copy list.

So all you have to do is just add you binary to the project as an item.

But to copy it to the output directory remotely, it has to be in the output directory locally. It sounds like that is what you're trying to do (C# DllImporting C/C++ code).

Copy the C# project's output to the C++ project output directory, locally on Windows. The output directory will look like something like this:

> C:\Users\iontodirel\Documents\visual studio
>   2015\Projects\ConsoleApplication50\ConsoleApplication50\bin\x64\Debug

ConsoleApplication50 is a C++ Linux Console Application project. The goal here is to get the directory structure correct, that's why you're making a copy of it, and not adding it as a link. After you copied it to the output directory, add the binary as an existing item, from the C++'s project output directory. You can use the Add - Existing Item dialog for this, or do it directly in the project file. After you do it, it will look like so in the project file:

```
<None Include="bin\x64\Debug\ConsoleApplication1.exe" />
```

Notice how the item is relative to the project directory, and it's in the output directory locally.

After you build, ConsoleApplication1.exe will be copied to ~/projects/ConsoleApplication50/bin/x64/Debug/ConsoleApplication1.exe.

Currently there is a limitation in that you can control the directory structure inside the project directory, but not outside. Today, the way you can overcome this limitation is by using the Remote Post-Build Event, this is under Build Events in the Property Pages, and with this you can execute arbitrary commands on the remote system, one of which can be copying a file from one location on the remote system, to another location on the remote system.